# Extending Rcpp::as for custom classes depending on Rcpp.h

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, s-expression

I'm working on an Rcpp sparse matrix class that uses both `Rcpp::IntegerVector` (row/column pointers) and a templated `std::vector<T>`. The rationale is that overhead in deep-copying the integer pointer vectors (`@i`, `@p`) in extremely large sparse-matrices can be avoided by simply leaving them as pointers to R objects, and consistently, microbenchmarks show that this approach takes almost exactly half the time as conversion to `Eigen::SparseMatrix<T>` and `arma::SpMat<T>` while using less memory.

**Bare-bones Rcpp sparse matrix class**

```
namespace SpRcpp {

    template<typename T>
    class SpMatrix {

    public:
        Rcpp::IntegerVector i, p;
        std::vector<T> x;
        unsigned int n_row, n_col;

        // constructor for the class from an Rcpp::S4 object
        SpMatrix(Rcpp::S4& mat) {
            Rcpp::IntegerVector dims = mat.slot("Dim");
            n_row = (unsigned int)dims[0];
            i = mat.slot("i");
            p = mat.slot("p");
            x = Rcpp::as<std::vector<T>>(mat.slot("x"));
        };
        // other constructors, class methods, iterators, etc.
    };
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<float> SpRcpp_SpMatrix(Rcpp::S4& mat) {
    SpRcpp::SpMatrix<float> A(mat);
    return A.x;
}
```

This works!

However, I'd like to have Rcpp implicitly convert an S4 dgCMatrix object, for example, to an `SpRcpp::SpMatrix` object to enable functions like the following:

**Implicit Rcpp wrapping**

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<float> SpRcpp_SpMatrix2(SpRcpp::SpMatrix<float>& mat) {
    return mat.x;
}
```

Such is a case of using `Rcpp::as`.

I've tried the following:

```
namespace Rcpp {
    namespace traits {
        template <typename T>
        class Exporter< SpRcpp::SpMatrix<T> > {
        public:
            Exporter(SEXP x) { Rcpp::S4 mat = x; }
            SpRcpp::SpMatrix<T> get() {
                return SpRcpp::SpMatrix<T>(mat);
            }
        private: Rcpp::S4 mat;
        };
    }
}
```

This compiles, and I know that the `SpRcpp::SpMatrix<T>(Rcpp::S4& x)` constructor works, but when I attempt to feed a dgCMatrix into `SpRcpp_SpMatrix()` I get the error:

`Error in SpRcpp_SpMatrix2(A) : Not an S4 object.`

I presume this is because I've declared the following before all my class declaration:

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
```

Per the docs [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-extending.pdf), the [RcppGallery example](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/custom-templated-wrap-and-as-for-seamingless-interfaces/), and the [RcppArmadillo](https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/blob/master/inst/include/RcppArmadilloAs.h#L97) implementation, `#include <Rcpp.h>` must not precede the `Rcpp::as` and `Rcpp::wrap` functions, but in my case I can't do that because my class definition requires `Rcpp.h`.

**QUESTION:** How do I create an `Rcpp::as` for `SpRcpp::SpMatrix` from an `Rcpp::S4` dgCMatrix when the `SpMatrix` class depends on `Rcpp.h`?

Comment: From glancing at this, isn't that a run-time error (R trying to coerce to/from S4) so that your attempted fix compile-time layout has no bearing?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel So you are saying that my use of `Rcpp::Exporter` is correct and should be working in theory? The object exists as an S4 object, `isS4(x)` returns `TRUE`, so what would trigger a run-time error, and why would this get triggered in my case and not for RcppArmadillo/Eigen?

Comment: No that is not what I said.  At least not explicitly.  You could try forward declarations, and / or cast your new matrix in terms of `Armadillo` vectors as we do have zero-copy constructors for those too.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Interesting idea! So to be clear, Rcpp conversion to an arma::ivec or arma::uvec is zero-copy?  Why then is conversion to arma::SpMat a deep copy for all three vectors (i, p, and x)?  Is an arma::dvec or arma::fvec also zero-copy?  I would assume a float vector would have to get copied, no?

Comment: Please slow down and think (and/or measure as you otherwise appear to be doing).  What R types would `uvec` or `float` be zero-copied to? Exactly.  But it does hold for `int` and `double`.  Anyway, now and here is not the place for an extended discussion, we do have a mailing list for a reason.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Perfect, thanks for your extremely prompt help once again! I'll see what I can do with RcppArmadillo vectors and post on the mailing list with further questions if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite simple to create an Rcpp SparseMatrix class!  I was overthinking it.

```
#include <rcpp.h>

// Rcpp for sparse matrices (spRcpp)
namespace Rcpp {
    class SparseMatrix {
    public:
        Rcpp::IntegerVector i, p;
        Rcpp::NumericVector x;
        int n_rows, n_cols;

        // constructor
        SparseMatrix(Rcpp::S4 mat) {
            Rcpp::IntegerVector dim = mat.slot("Dim");
            i = mat.slot("i");
            p = mat.slot("p");
            x = mat.slot("x");
            n_rows = (int)dim[0];
            n_cols = (int)dim[1];
        };
    };
}

namespace Rcpp {
    template <> Rcpp::SparseMatrix as(SEXP mat) {
        return Rcpp::SparseMatrix(mat);
    }
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector toRcppSparseMatrix(Rcpp::SparseMatrix& A) {
    return A.x;
}
```

Given a `Matrix::dgCMatrix`, `mat`, calling `toRcppSparseMatrix(mat)` returns non-zero values in 1-2 microseconds for 25 million values. This is in contrast to RcppArmadillo or RcppEigen sparse matrix conversions which take about 250 milliseconds for this same matrix and runs a deep copy in-memory.

As Dirk suggested, using RcppArmadillo `ivec` and `dvec` were very efficient, but still created shallow copies which resulted in ~100 milliseconds runtime and consumed some memory.

Obviously, the above approach is restricted to double types, so float operations are not possible without a deep copy.